# Components in xamarin forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

When using MVVM in Xamarin Forms, our "custom components" should be reusable views with ViewModels or reusable views with code behind?

Let's say this "reusable view" is, for example, a relative layout with some stack layouts, entries and labels inside it, and it has some visual behavior, data binding, etc.

Comment: Derive it from ContentView

Comment: Hi Yuri S, thanks for your comment.

Comment: What about the presentation logic,  should I do it in a view model and reuse this view model inside another view models? Or do it in the code behind so de component is valid by  itself

Comment: this is design decision. Depends what you need from this component, how complicated it is, etc. You probably need some Bindable properties, may be expose some events. This question is too broad to answer